# image does not appear on github pages

Tags: javascript, html, github-pages

I wrote a simple HTML file to put an image to a canvas.  It runs on localhost but not in github pages.

The image `starry-night.jpg` is on the same folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>

<canvas id="vincent"></canvas>

<script>

        var width  = 960;
        var height = 500;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('vincent');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width  = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        var image = new Image();
        image.src= "starry-night.jpg";
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        console.log("done");

</script>

</body>
```

Here is a link to it not working: http://monsieurcactus.github.io/LearnElm/canvas-example.html

Here is a snippet also not working:

```js
        var width  = 960;
        var height = 500;
        var canvas = document.getElementById('vincent');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width  = width;
        canvas.height = height;

        var image = new Image();
        image.src= "http://monsieurcactus.github.io/LearnElm/starry-night.jpg";
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        console.log("done");
```

```html
<canvas id="vincent"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the image's source with the **src** attribute *makes the browser to trigger an HTTP request for getting the image*, and **you need to wait for the image to be loaded** before drawing it. Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>

<canvas id="vincent"></canvas>

<script>

    var width  = 960;
    var height = 500;
    var canvas = document.getElementById('vincent');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width  = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    var image = new Image();
    image.src= "http://monsieurcactus.github.io/LearnElm/starry-night.jpg";

    image.onload = function() {
         ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
         console.log("done");
    }

</script>

</body>
```

Note: Here we need an absolute url because this example is being served outside of **monsieurcactus.github.io/LearnElm/**